# Using Windows Batch Script Can I Use A For Loop To Iterate Multi-Line File And Run Multiple Commands

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to iterate a flat text file containing a Windows directory listing and run multiple commands against each line assigning each line to a variable.  I then want to echo each resulting output from each command into a comma-delimited file.  Yes, I understand batch programming might not be the best choice but am somewhat limited at the moment.  Here is where I am at with it:

```
@echo off
setlocal
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:: There could be spaces in the filename, thus using delims
FOR /f "delims=?" %%a in (e:\multiline_textfile.txt) do (
set filename=%%a
CALL :PROG1
CALL :PROG2
CALL :PROG3
CALL :ENDPROG

:PROG1
FOR /f "delims=?" %%h in ('e:\apps\exe1.exe -s "!filename!"') do set result11=%%h

:PROG2
FOR /f "delims=?" %%i in ('e:\apps\exe1.exe -b"!filename!"') do set result2=%%i

:PROG3
FOR /f "delims=?" %%j in ('e:\apps\exe2.exe -c "!filename!"') do set result3=%%j

:ENDPROG
echo !result1!,!result2!,!result3!
)

---
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:: There could be spaces in the filename, thus using delims
FOR /f "delims=" %%a in (e:\multiline_textfile.txt) do (
set "filename=%%a"
CALL :PROG1
CALL :PROG2
CALL :PROG3
CALL :ENDPROG
)
echo here endeth your batch mainline
goto :eof

:PROG1
FOR /f "delims=" %%h in ('e:\apps\exe1.exe -s "!filename!"') do set "result1=%%h"
goto :eof

:PROG2
FOR /f "delims=" %%i in ('e:\apps\exe1.exe -b"!filename!"') do set "result2=%%i"
goto :eof

:PROG3
FOR /f "delims=" %%j in ('e:\apps\exe2.exe -c "!filename!"') do set "result3=%%j"
goto :eof

:ENDPROG
echo !result1!,!result2!,!result3!
goto :eof
```

You don't need the initial `SETLOCAL` - one is quite sufficient.

Labels are simply MARKERS in a batch program - they don't affect flow. The most common way to return in a `CALL`ed routine is to `GOTO :EOF` where the colon is REQUIRED and the label `:EOF` is implicit and should NOT be declared.

Bad idea to attempt to use labels within a `FOR` loop like that. Might work with later versions, but not with earlier. Note the `FOR` loop's ending <kbd>)</kbd> has been moved...

Whereas `!var!` works, it is not necessary in this case because each subroutine is essentially a whole new program which inherits the main environment as it stood at the `CALL`. Hence each `!var!` could be replaced by `%var%` and the `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` need only be a `SETLOCAL`. You only need to use delayedexpansion where an ordinary environment variable's value is to be used after being changed in a compound statement (like a `FOR` over multiple lines, for instance)

Comment: I removed the ? from delims as it seems like you actually need no delimiters, and added quotes to set statements to improve the reliability.